# How to do min() in tailwind CSS

Tags: css, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

How to do I use the min() function like the following in tailwind

```
width: min(50vw, 200px);
```

I have tried min-w-[200px], but it does not work as intended. Is it possible in tailwind CSS?

Thanks

Comment: 'Fraid not, but you can use `@apply` and create your own class as an "alias".

Comment: `w-[min(50vw,200px)]` does the trick